# How To Outlining only one Toggle in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Here Is my piece of code And I want to Toggle One Outlining in my LoadItemTrackingGrid(), Please give me A shortcut of all outlining.

```
protected void LoadItemTrackingGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadItemTrackingGrid();
}

private bool IsEditModeProductGroup()
{
    return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblParentProductId.Text));
}

protected void lnkProductGroupAdd_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlProductGroup.SelectedIndex == 0)
        txtProductGroupName.Text = string.Empty;
    else
        txtProductGroupName.Text = ddlProductGroup.SelectedItem.Text;
    popupProductGroup.Show();
    txtProductGroupName.Focus();
}

protected void btnSaveProductGroup_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsValidProductGroup())
    {
        popupProductGroup.Show();
        return;
    }
    int? ParentProductId = SaveProductGroup();
    LoadProductGroup();
    ddlProductGroup.SelectedValue = ParentProductId.ToString();
    ddlProductGroup_OnSelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
}
```

Comment: Dear upvoter, just because it has code may not imply it's a good question. Particularly when it's about keyboard short-cuts in a tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlining only One Toggle => Ctrl + M + M

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need??

[image: Outlining]

Did you really search for this and couldn't find any answer?

[All Visual Studio Shortcuts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)